# Write process id to file in Gitlab CI/CD script

Tags: linux, bash, gitlab-ci

After building front- and backend with Gitlab CI/CD jobs I try to copy executables on server and rerun backend server.

Expected behaviour: kill process with pid from file /var/run/backend.pid, then run new one process in background and write new pid to same file.

Actual behaviour: everything is well, but file /var/run/backend.pid is empty (actually only new line character)

```
script:  
  - ssh root@draft.<...project name...>.tech "pkill -F /var/run/<...project name...>-backend.pid;rm /var/run/<...project name...>-backend.pid;/var/www/<...project name...>/backend/bin/backend > /var/log/<...project name...>-backend.log 2>&1 & disown;echo $! > /var/run/<...project name...>-backend.pid"
```

Please help me with my deploy. I do not know what cann be wrong, because locally same command works well.

Answer (score 0):

Try and check if the file is created in the first place, by running only the first part of your command:

```
ssh root@draft.<...project name...>.tech  "pkill -F /var/run/<...project name...>-backend.pid"
```

That will validate that:

- gitlab-ci runs with an account which is able to do the `ssh root@draft.<...project name...>.tech`
- and the `pkill` command does actually generate a non-empty `backend.pid` file

Comment: `ssh` works well. `pkill` too. I do not understand what you mean by "pkill does generate". `pkill` uses pid from file to kill server process before restart it. Problem is somewhere here: `echo $! > /var/run/<...project name...>-backend.pid`. I assume that Gitlab CI tries to use variable $! from CI/CD options, that is missing. But I need real bash variable with last command pid

Comment: @Sasha I meant, does it generate a pid file?

Comment: Yes. Last part of script generates empty (only new line char) pid file